# Unexplained excessive memory allocation on TensorFlow GPU (bi-LSTM and CRF)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorboard

I'm using TensorFlow to develop an NLP model. Here's the graph of the model, shown on Tensorboard. This model is referred to as the 'simple model' further ahead.

[image]

In order to improve the results, I want to train a joint model, where I duplicate the block marked with 'TEMPLATE MODEL TO REPLICATE' in the graph above. This block includes two bi-directional LSTM's. The joint model is shown below.

[image]

In the joint model, we have two instances of the template block from the simple model, marked with "REPLICA 1" and "REPLICA 2" in joint model's graph shown above. The only difference between the simple model and the joint model is that in the joint model the input of the "CRF" block is the average of the output of the two replicas. So if we had only one replica in the joint model, then it should yield the same result as the simple model.

For this averaging, I just use `tf.stack` and `tf.reduce_mean`, as follows:

```
with tf.name_scope("average_logits"):
    # Stack the list of logits tensors with rank R into a single
    # tensor with rank R+1
    logits = tf.stack(logits,
                      axis=0,
                      name="stacked_logits")
    # Average out this tensor over dimension 0 (models dimension)
    self.logits = tf.reduce_mean(logits,
                                 axis=0,
                                 name="average_logits")
```

Now, running on GPU, the simple model occupies about 700MB of space, while the joint model occupies about 4GB, and I am unable to find an explanation for this, since the variables inside the "context_bi-lstm" and "chars" blocks take at most 200MB, in total. This excessive allocation is a problem for me right now since I have an 8GB GPU and want to run a model with more than 2 replicas, and that generates an OOM error.

So I have no idea where this drastic increase in memory comes from. Might I be executing some really memory expensive operation with the `tf.stack` and `tf.mean_reduce`?

Comment: Does the model include the optimization nodes? Not sure if that's the case, but maybe it could be related to the increased complexity of gradient computation (If the answer to the first question is yes, maybe you could compare the memory required by the inference architecture for each case, without the optimisation).